# Check if the list is sorted in Ocaml

Tags: list, sorting, recursion, ocaml

Why the code below is wrong? 
Even though the first two results are correct but the last one should return false, it returns true instead. Why so?

```
let rec is_sorted x = match x with
|h::h2::[] -> if h <= h2 then true else false
|h::h2::t -> if h <= h2 then is_sorted h2::t else false

# is_sorted [4;5;6;5;9];;
- : bool = false
# is_sorted [4;5;6;7;9];;
- : bool = true
# is_sorted [4;5;6;18;9];;
- : bool = true
```

Comment: I think you may have modified the code before you pasted since all your test cases work in my terminal after I added parenthesis around `h2::t`. Although this code is wrong for different reasons then the set of input values you've tested against.

Comment: I'm not an ocaml expert, but fwiw, the logic looks reasonable to me. Have you tried with a shorter input, e.g. [18;9]?

Comment: Ahh, that was it. Just had to put paranthesis around. Thank you. Can you please share why is this code wrong?

Comment: What happens if your list is `[1]` ? Or the empty list ? Also, `if <cond> then true else false` is redundant, just return `<cond>`. Similarly, the last line is equivalent to `h <= h2 && is_sorted (h2::t)`.

Comment: The compiler, in this case, will tell you that the matching is not exhaustive. It's good form to heed all those warnings.

Comment: Got it now. I wasn't paying attention to warnings but yeah, I did forget the base cases. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

I'll write the following:

```
let rec is_sorted x = match x with
  | [] -> true
  | h::[] -> true
  | h::h2::t -> if h <= h2 then is_sorted (h2::t) else false;;
```

Then:

```
# is_sorted [];;
- : bool = true
# is_sorted [1];;
- : bool = true
# is_sorted [4;5;6;5;9];;
- : bool = false
# is_sorted [4;5;6;7;9];;
- : bool = true
# is_sorted [4;5;6;18;9];;
- : bool = false
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter:

```
let rec is_sorted = function
  | x::y::l -> x <= y && is_sorted (y::l)
  | _ -> true
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

```
let rec sorted x =
   match x with
   | [] -> true
   | [_] -> true
   | a::b::t when a <= b -> sorted (b::t)
   | _ -> false
;;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will check if an int list is sorted in ascending or descending:

```
let is_sorted l =
    let rec aux l cmp = 
    match l with
    | [] | [_] -> true
    | x :: ((y :: _) as t) -> cmp x y && aux t cmp
    in 
    aux l ( <= ) || aux l ( >= )
```